# Android Studio/compiler not use external build

Tags: android, android-studio

I import my project from eclipse in to Android Studio version 0.1
But now I update to version 0.2.3 
The ide notify me to use external build in (Ctrl+Alt+S)/Compiler
I also check use external build but when I exit Android Studio
and Open Android Studio again the use external build is uncheck and 
I have to re-check "use external build" every time.

Is there any solution?

ps.
I save my project in dropbox and sync with bitbucket.

Comment: Have you tried to delete .idea directories and re-import the project?

Comment: I try to delete .idea then try to import but there is a error "Cannot load .idea  The file doesn't exist" may be I'll try to delete during run the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to import project back to eclipse and update eclipse and Android SDK Manager then in Eclipse, select File > Export.In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.Select the project you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish. Then re import to Android Studio. I found an error about build tool revision 16.0.2 so I open build.gradle in text editor and change 16.0.2 to 17 and every thing goes very well.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: It's doesn't work.

AFAIR, importing _build.gradle_ never worked and it’s well known bug for 4GB computers.

I was wondering could you tell what was changed in .idea files, so we can apply the change manually, please?

Unable to start the daemon process.

This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.

For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.

Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Please read below process output to find out more:

Comment: So you want what are in .idea?